# Store triggered events on DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I store events triggered in DOM. Suppose I have one div. I want to change the color of div when I mouseover on it. Again change the color of div to previous color after mouseout. Again, change color when I click on div showing as active.

My code are as follows:

```
  $(document).on("mouseover", ".imgpayment", function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background","#89C4F4");
 });

 $(document).on("mouseout", ".imgpayment", function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background","none");
 });

 $(document).on("click", ".imgpayment", function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background","#59ABE3");
    $(this).parent().find(".the-terms").prop('checked', true);
    $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
 });
```

The problem is that:

How can I know that click events has already been triggered in div so that mouseout events doesn't trigger because it changes the color to default and I can't show that div is clicked and active.

Comment: Use CSS classes and the :hover pseudo selector

Comment: you may `console.log('this is the case')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `css` method for style manipulation. You can see why - it's very inconvenient in inflexible. There will be no problem if you toggle classes.

```js
$(document).on("mouseover", ".imgpayment", function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});

$(document).on("mouseout", ".imgpayment", function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
});

$(document).on("click", ".imgpayment", function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().find(".the-terms").prop('checked', true);
    $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```css
.active {
    background: #89C4F4;
}
.selected {
    background: #59ABE3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="imgpayment">TEST <small>Hover to highlight, click to select</small></div>
</div>
```

Comment: THank you. Simple logic I already implemented but isn't it possible from jquery

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "but isn't it possible from jquery"? What isn't possible?

Comment: I mean isn't it possible to do with just jquery css method directly without toggling class. Like storing click event handlers and if already click then not to trigger mouseout event.

Comment: Well of course it's possible, but I strongly advice against going this way. But yes, you can store state flag in object property or data attribute (`$(this).data('clicked', true)`). For example, http://jsfiddle.net/L93v45gf/.